# how to find value of next index in each for loop iteration in xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
 import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
 at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
 declare variable $totalhosts := xdmp:host-name(xdmp:group-hosts(xdmp:group()));

 for $h in $totalhosts
 let $ind := fn:index-of($h, 2)
 return $h[$ind]
```

If somewhere I put in the code

```
let $ind :=2
```

and then I `return $h[$ind]` it should return the value at `index ind=2`

Please help how can I do this

Comment: It's more helpful if you show what you want to produce from a given set of inputs. The fact that you have a list of hostnames from the group-hosts is irrelevant. You could simplify the question by using a static sequence i.e. `("a","b","c","d")` and then give an example of what you are trying to produce from it.

Comment: I don't think `fn:index-of()` is what you want to use(with that function you would give it a hostname to look for, not a number/position), and when selecting from the set of hostnames with the predicate, you want to use `$totalhosts` and not `$h` - but you also need to ensure that your `$ind` has a useful value.

Comment: Indeed. To get a good answer to this question (a) cut out anything that's specific to MarkLogic (because that increases your audience), and (b) show the input and desired output. Explain the problem you want to solve, not just the way you are trying to solve it.

Comment: I understand but my question is a mix of marklogic logic building with xquery. $totalhost gives me five host names - host1.bu.com host2.bu.com host3.bu.com ... anmd so on.. My question is that if i pass the index of any of these how can i get the value returned as a host? i hope i m clear.

Comment: It's not clear to me or the experts that already answered.  You can also do

for $h at $index in $totalhosts

if you need to know where you are in the sequence, if that helps.